# Sonar 5.2 & Cobertura Plugin doesn't work

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, cobertura, sonarqube5.2

We upgraded to Sonar 5.2. But now, the task to process the sonar report fails:

```
2015.12.21 16:08:20 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerRunnableImpl] Failed to execute task AVHFFR9SqYJURQAYr8yb
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There's no changeset on line 59
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:125) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.scm.ScmInfoImpl.getChangesetForLine(ScmInfoImpl.java:64) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.scm.DbScmInfo.getChangesetForLine(DbScmInfo.java:69) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.NewCoverageMeasuresStep$NewCoverageCounter.initialize(NewCoverageMeasuresStep.java:391) ~[so
```

If I uninstall the Cobertura Plugin which has version 1.6.3, then the report process works fine. But that's no solution for me because I need these reports. Did anybody succeed to solve this error in another way?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

1) Your issue seems related to [this discussion on SonarQube's group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/sonarqube/34ihklXlM9Q). Check if you have such `line number="0"` in your `cobertura.xml file`. Unfortunately the fix is planned for SonarQube 5.4 (i.e. 04/Mar/16.)

2) Depending on your exact needs related to Cobertura reports generation and if you're using Maven, you can try to use [QualInsight Maven Cobertura plugin](https://github.com/QualInsight/qualinsight-mojo-cobertura) to generate your Cobertura reports. This plugin provides the `qualinsight-mojo-cobertura-core` mojo, an alternative to the `cobertura-maven-plugin` mojo you're probably using if your build is Maven based. QualInsight Maven Cobertura plugin generates separate reports for UTs, ITs, and combined Overall Test coverage. It generates standard `cobertura.xml` reports, but also is able to convert them to [SonarQube Generic Test Coverage plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Generic+Test+Coverage) format.

Maybe generated reports by `qualinsight-mojo-cobertura-core` won't contain data causing issues + maybe using SonarQube's Generic Coverage plugin instead of SonarQube's Cobertura plugin won't cause the exception you get (it was released 9 days ago and tested towards SQ 5.2, while the Cobertura plugin was last released in September 2014)

If want to give it a try and need help / have questions with this solution, just ask (I'm the developer QualInsight Maven Cobertura plugin.)

Regards,

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply and help. I tried it with the Generic Coverage Plugin. So you think I a can generate the reports with Cobertura as it is and then user the Generic Coverage Plugin on sonar instead of the cobertura plugin? Maven has a lot of these warnings then '[WARNING] Class 'net/sourceforge/cobertura/coveragedata/LightClassmapListener' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.' And finally it can't generate a report \target\site\cobertura\coverage.xml: Unknown coverage version: 2.1.1. This parser only handles version 1.

Comment: Hi, no you won't be able to use the generic coverage plugin with `cobertura-maven-plugin` as the output format is not understood by the generic coverage plugin. That's why I wrote you should try to use it in conjunction with the alternative Maven plugin `qualinsight-mojo-corbertura`.